# Не работает npm test в Jest

Tags: node.js, babel, jest

При попытке вызвать test() в консоли появляется ошибка:

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
> locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
> dependency:
>
> "babel-jest": "^26.6.0"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
> automatically. However, a different version of babel-jest was detected
> higher up in the tree:
>
> /home/user/Desktop/Oleg/prep/node_modules/babel-jest (version:
> 27.0.6)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
> hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add
> SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will
> permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
> order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
> not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if /home/user/Desktop/Oleg/prep/node_modules/babel-jest is outside your project directory.
>    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
>    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-jest.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
> in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
> in case you want to proceed anyway.

Прошел все описанные шаги. Удалял node_modules, lock-файлы, использовал yarn. Не помогло.

Создал файл .env, добавил туда строку `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`. В результате еще одна ошибка:

> Validation Error:
>
> Watch plugin jest-watch-typeahead/filename cannot be found. Make
> sure the watchPlugins configuration option points to an existing node
> module.
>
> Configuration Documentation:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html

Установил jest-watch-typeahead

Появляется еще одна ошибка:

> Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these
> Jest options:
>
> • clearMocks   • collectCoverageFrom   • coveragePathIgnorePatterns
> • coverageReporters   • coverageThreshold   • displayName   •
> extraGlobals   • globalSetup   • globalTeardown   • moduleNameMapper
> • resetMocks   • resetModules   • restoreMocks   • snapshotSerializers
> • testMatch   • transform   • transformIgnorePatterns   •
> watchPathIgnorePatterns.
>
> These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not
> currently supported by Create React App:
>
> • watchPlugins
>
> If you wish to override other Jest options, you need to eject from the
> default setup. You can do so by running npm run eject but remember
> that this is a one-way operation. You may also file an issue with
> Create React App to discuss supporting more options out of the box.

Подскажите, что делать дальше

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11043#issuecomment-874730024

Comment: @nörbörnën установил, не помогло. См. тему.